# How can I create a foreign key relationship in Visual Studio when writing out the tables?

Tags: c#, database, foreign-keys

I have the 2 tables in the picture below and want to add a foreign key relationship between them with the ServiceID being the foreign key

[My 2 tables side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haayM.png)
[My Database Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbBZy.png)

Comment: You mean how to declare a relationship using attributes rather than fluent syntax in EF core ? Have you read [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) any? Is there something in it you don't understand, that we can help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to ServiceStatistics:

```
[ForeignKey("ServiceLogRefId")]
public ServiceLog ServiceLog {get; set; }

public int ServiceLogRefId {get; set; }
```

May be a slight difference in annotation given version (you haven't specified in your question).

Comment: Do you mean the VS version? then its VS Enterprise 2019 16.11.7

Answer (score 0):

your code can like this:

```
public class LoginLog
{
    .
    .
    .
    public int ServiceStateId{ get; set; }
    public ServiceState ServiceState{ get; set; }
}
public class ServiceState 
{
    .
    . 
    .
    public ICollection<LoginLog> LoginLogs{ get; set; }
}
```

also you get all info about relations in this link:[Relation in EF](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx)